# Sudoku solver finding a solution for unsolvable sudoku

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I have written a Sudoku solver and it works just fine when sudoku is solvable. However when sudoku is unsolvable it changes the original numbers of the puzzle when backtracking.

```
bool Sudoku::solve(int row, int col){
if (board[row][col] != 0){
    int next_col = col;
    int next_row = row;

    next_col++;

    if (next_col > 8){
        next_row++;
        next_col = 0;
    }

    if (next_row > 8){
        return true;
    } else {
        if (solve(next_row, next_col))
            return true;
    }
}

for (int number = 1; number <= 9; number++){
    board[row][col] = number;

    if (check_row(row, number)
     && check_col(col, number)
     && check_box(row, col, number)){
        int next_row = row;
        int next_col = col+1;

        if (next_col > 8){
            next_col = 0;
            next_row++;
        }

        if (next_row > 8){
            return true;
        }

        if (solve(next_row, next_col))
            return true;
     }
}

board[row][col] = 0;
return false;
```

}

board is a 2D int array. I know I could use some kind of structure instead of integer, which would store if the number was originally there or not, however this solution is not really appealing to me. Is there any other way ?

Comment: It's trying to make it solvable...

Comment: Spontaneous AI?  Awesome. You should probably patent that right away.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the check at the beginning, when the cell is set,

```
if (board[row][col] != 0){
    int next_col = col;
    int next_row = row;

    next_col++;

    if (next_col > 8){
        next_row++;
        next_col = 0;
    }

    if (next_row > 8){
        return true;
    } else {
        if (solve(next_row, next_col))
            return true;
    }
}
```

add an

```
else {
    return false;
}
```

or change the last to

```
return solve(next_row, next_col);
```

to avoid changing the given numbers. As is, if the puzzle cannot be solved - even after guessing a previous cell wrongly where the original could be solved - it happily goes on to change the number in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a set of all the visited locations.

An example implementation would be to create `std::set<pair<int, int> > visited` that contains each location that has been visited. Then if the location has been visited, don't change the value.